# Importing pygments' highlighting to vim

Tags: vim, python, mysql, syntax-highlighting

Usually, `vim` does very good job in highlighting, using the packaged syntax files. Unfortunately, it does bad job with `MySQL`. At first, I looked everywhere for a better MySQL vim syntax file, with no luck. Later I started writing my own MySQL highlighter, based on the original one, and based on the updated MySQL manual. However, this task has turned out to be more complex that what I originally thought it would be.

Then I found out `pygments` does nice job with `MySQL`. Of course, this is not a fair contest, as `pygments` may do more serious lexing than vim; however, a deeper look into the `MySqlLexer` class of `pygments` reveals this is a `RegexLexer`, which probably have no further capabilities than the vim highlighter.

So my question is this: can you think of a simple way to convert a lexer from `pygments`, or at least a `RegexLexer`, into a vim syntax file?

Comment: Not really a solution, but pyvim (https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/pyvim) supports syntax highlighting via pygments.